# Best code style

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

What's the best way to fill the value of the variable. The method should get the picture from the archive in NSData type and write error if the problems.

```
- (void) svg:(void(^)(NSData *imData))image ByIndex:(NSInteger)index error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error;

- (void) svg:(NSData **imData)image ByIndex:(NSInteger)index error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error;

- (NSData *) imageByIndex:(NSInteger)index error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error;
```

Or other variant?

Comment: Apple recommends that you don't use 'get' in method names.

Comment: @CW0007007 That's not exactly true. One should think very careful when to do this, but it can be appropriate, just like in getBytes on NSData.

Comment: I think this should not be closed. Naming methods is *key* for good programming. It's one of the most important things, and it's often done so wrong. This question should rather rank very high on this site.

Comment: @CW0007007 Thanx's. Edit Edited first post

Comment: @eiko This has nothing to do with "being carefully". There is a rule for it.

Comment: @CW0007007 Can you show me a link to that recommendation?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad No, there is no such general rule. While ordinary properties should never be be named getSomething, this doesn't hold for more complex logic like in getBytes: of NSData. That's what I mean with "use careful". Use it when the logic asks for it. (In this case, I doubt it.)

Comment: I know that. Do you know "rhetorical questions"? BTW: This rule does not even apply to properties. It simply depends on the level of indirections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's synchronous:

```
- (NSData *)dataForImageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error;
```

or, if it is asynchronous:

```
- (void)requestDataForImageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index completionHandler:(void(^)(NSData *data, NSError *error)completionHandler;
```

---

Or if you wanted to specify nullability for the sake of Swift interoperability:

```
- (NSData * __nullable)imageDataForIndex:(NSInteger)index error:(NSError * __nullable __autoreleasing * __nullable)error {
```

and

```
- (void)requestDataForImageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index completionHandler:(void (^ __nonnull)(NSData * __nullable data, NSError * __nullable error))completionHandler
```

Comment: Thanks for undeleting. This shows how concise naming makes code reading and understanding easy. Using the standard conventions, (i.e. "for" and not "by") makes it accessible by virtually every Objective-C programmer.

Comment: @Rob Thnx a lot! It's what I wanted!